# I'm creating a detailed component spec for an input field in iOS and I don't know exactly how to specify certain accessibility details

Tags: accessibility, ios, input-fields, component, design-system

I'm building a detailed accessibility spec for an iOS input field component for a design system. I want to outline in the spec how voiceover should work.

The design system needs an input field that looks more like a traditional web or Material input, with a box around the input itself, which iOS doesn't seem to offer natively.

I know I want the voiceover to say, but I'm uncertain how to relate those to the correct accessibility attributes, like "accessibilityLabel".

ON FOCUS:

- [Read label] (accessibilityLabel)
- [Read entered value if any, or placeholder text, if any] (accessibilityValue, but what about placeholder?)
- [Read hint text, or error text, if present] (?)
- "Text field" (accessibilityRole)
- "Double-tap to edit" (accessibilityHint)

ON EDIT:

- [Read entered value, if any] (accessibilityValue)
- "Character mode insertion point at [start/end]" (accessibilityHint?)
- "Use rotor to access misspelled words" (accessibilityHint?)

How does placeholder text translate?
Am I mapping these correctly?
How specific do I need to be? Is this overkill?
Am I missing something?